# create mysql table with repetitive primary keys

Tags: mysql

Question: (I am learning MySQL and PHP) I want to create a MySQL table with repetitive primary keys on mac system.

I have CSV file like following with over 1000 rows;

a;1;bit;4

a;3;bit;7

b;1;bit;1

b;2;bit;10

b;4;but;1

and I tried following commands:

```
create table new (  
     P VARCHAR(8) int  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key, 
     P VARCHAR(8), 
     Pposition VARCHAR(30), 
     Ptype VARCHAR(30)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

load data local infile '/Users/admin/Desktop/ab.csv' 
   INTO TABLE new 
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY';';
```

> Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
>
> Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1

Can you please suggest me the right and efficient way to solve this problem. Thanks !

Comment: the values in a primary key column must be unique from each other, they can't be repeated. Or is that not what you meant by "repetitive primary keys"? The question isn't 100% clear as to what you're asking

Comment: Ok let me put it in this way, I want to store a CSV file in above format into a mySQL table where values in the first column are not unique, how can I do that ?

Comment: Solve what problem? The problem of having a primary (unique) key on `P` ... the first column, and trying to bring in non-unique data into it?

Comment: @ADyson just write up the answer. You got my vote coming. We have a dozen questions flying in, must move on to the next one.

Comment: At the risk of repeating others - The primary key by definition MUST be unique.

Comment: I see many things wrong: (1) primary key must have unique values; (2) you can't have two columns both named `P` in one table; (3) If you want the first `P` column to be auto-increment, it should be `int(10) unsigned` not varchar(8); (4) as a naming convention, you should call the auto-increment column `id`; (5) use `show warnings` command to see what warnings you got after executing the query; (6) I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @ADyson my upvote has been registered.

Comment: @Drew appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about the purpose of primary keys - you should read up on this.

To solve this specific problem:

1) Your first column P can't be designated as a primary key. The values you're trying to import into it are not unique.

2) You've given this field two types - varchar(8) - which means text up to 8 characters long, and int - meaning integers (whole numbers). It's either one or the other. Based on your sample input it ought to be the varchar.

3) Giving this field the auto-increment property makes no sense - this is meant for integer primary key fields, and tells the table to automatically pick the next un-used integer value and put it in that column whenever a new row is created. Your field is (or should be) neither an integer or a key field.

4) There are two columns named P. You can't do this. Column names must be unique. Give one of them a different name. Try this table definition:

```
create table new (  
 P VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
 P2 int, 
 Pposition VARCHAR(30), 
 Ptype VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Or, if you want to add a unique primary key automatically, so you can uniquely reference the rows after the import, you could try:

```
create table new (
 ID int not null auto_increment primary key,
 P VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL, 
 P2 int, 
 Pposition VARCHAR(30), 
 Ptype VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the first version of your answer. But following load command does not to add all the data into the table: 

load data local infile '/Users/admin/ab.csv' INTO TABLE new COLUMNS TERMINATED BY';' lines TERMINATED BY '\n';

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Ok, so what does it do instead? Any errors? Any data in the table, or none at all?

Comment: This is the complete message, (only first row from csv file to mysql data get loaded)
load data local infile '/Users/admin/ab.csv' INTO TABLE new COLUMNS TERMINATED BY';' lines TERMINATED BY '\n';

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: and is there definitely one row in the table?

Comment: No, it has around 250 rows. I converted a text file to CSV format to load it to MySQL table.

Comment: No I meant in the database table - after you attempt the load. The message says it affected one row. I wanted to double check it has actually loaded one row, and if so, what the contents are (are they what you expected for the first row of the file?)

Comment: Yes, ADyson, its only one row of data that is being uploaded and the contents are the first row of the CSV file, that I'm trying to make an MySQL table in db.

Comment: @user3698773 Ok it's not something I really have experience with - I helped with the table definition as I understand that. Maybe you should read the documentation of the load data command and see if you need to change any of the settings. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html . My knowledge is not really any better than yours on this part.

Comment: Thank you very much @ ADyson; I will try to do it myself.